# Deconstructing XPages Drop Down Button Menus on page Scroll

Tags: drop-down-menu, scroll, xpages, xsp

I'm using xpages extension library to generate drop down menus in the navigation with the following code:

```
<xe:dropDownButton disableTheme="true" styleClass="menuButton">
        <xe:this.treeNodes>
            <xe:basicContainerNode styleClass="menuTopLevel">
                <xe:this.children>
                    <xe:pageTreeNode label="Create New" page="NewInspection.xsp"
                        styleClass="menuItemSub1">
                    </xe:pageTreeNode>
                    <xe:pageTreeNode label="Reports" page="View.xsp"
                        styleClass="menuItemSub1">
                    </xe:pageTreeNode>
                </xe:this.children>
            </xe:basicContainerNode>
        </xe:this.treeNodes>
    </xe:dropDownButton>
```

The problem I'm having is that when the user is on a page that is scrollable (That is to say, the height of the page exceeds the height of the content area), and they scroll the page, the menu stays where it is drawn, if it is open, and does not scroll with the page content. I'm looking for a way to deconstruct any/all open menus if the page scrolls, but I'm not having any luck with this in XPages. Has anyone encountered something similar?

Comment: First question is are you using the application layout? If you are , is this menu on the menubar or the placebar? I think the menubar scrolls but the placebar stays in place.

Comment: I'm not using the application layout. I'm trying to utilize these controls free-form due to adapting this system from html that came from our in-house design team. Essentially replacing the html with equivalent structures in XPages. The element itself is just inside of an xe:listInline element, which itself is just in a panel.

Comment: I just tested and can confirm that this is not the case if the dropDownButton is used with applicationLayout. FYI.

Comment: Is there an alternative to using the applicationLayout? I don't want to be dependent on the OneUI system and I would prefer to use these controls in ways that are more convenient to our methodology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution for this one. Utilizing a code library to determine when I was on the iPad, I loaded a function that added an event that used Dojo to attach an onscroll event bound to the exterior form rather than the window itself. I had to embed this in a script block in my navigation custom control for some reason, it wouldn't attach if I put it elsewhere. Here's the code if anyone else needs it in the future.

```
dojo.ready( function() {
var object = dojo.byId('view:_id1')
//console.log(object);
dojo.connect(object, 'onscroll', this, function(event) {
    // console.log('scroll');
        var object1 = dojo.byId('#{id:adminDropDown}_ab_0_dropdown')
        if (object1 != null) {
            dojo.style(object1, "display", "none")
        }
        var object1 = dojo.byId('#{id:insDropDown}_ab_0_dropdown')
        if (object1 != null) {
            dojo.style(object1, "display", "none")
        }
        var object1 = dojo.byId('#{id:emDropDown}_ab_0_dropdown')
        if (object1 != null) {
            dojo.style(object1, "display", "none")
        }
        var object1 = dojo.byId('widget_view:_id1:DateEntry_dropdown')
        if (object1 != null) {
            dojo.style(object1, "display", "none")
        }
    });
```